# Why does TCPDF ignore my inline CSS?

Tags: php, css, tcpdf

I am trying to create a PDF file using TCPDF. But When I tried to insert inline CSS into the HTML, it's displaying a blank page! Here are a few lines of my HTML:

```
pdf->AddPage();

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);

$pdf->Write(0, 'Example of HTML Justification', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

// create some HTML content
$html = '
<div id="wrapper" style="width:900px;height:auto;margin:0 auto;">
<div id="header" style="width:900px;height:180px;border-bottom:2px solid #5a5a5a;">
<div id="img" style="width:174px;height:87px;position:relative;top:10px;left:350px;"><img src="Untitled Document_files/logoticket.png" /></div>
<div id="text" style="width:250px;position:relative;left:315px;top:20px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">E-TICKET/RESERVATION VOUCHER</div>
<div id="text2" style="width:200px;position:relative;left:345px;top:40px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;">Visit - www.bookings.7sisters.in</div>
</div>
<div id="mainContent">
<div id="icon" style="width:600px;
height:37px;
position:relative;
left:190px;
top:20px;">
<img src="Untitled D.....
```

etc.

I am inserting the code in [TCPDF example 39](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_039.phps). But the output is only the TCPDF logo and the line "Example of HTML Justification". What's the reason? Or it does not support inline CSS?

Answer (score 101):

TCPDF has a very limited CSS support. It doesn't support all attributes.

Currently, only the following CSS attributes are supported:

- font-family
- font-size
- font-weight
- font-style
- color
- background-color
- text-decoration
- width
- height
- text-align

So try removing the other attributes, and tell if it works.

Also, [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/forums) is an active forum for TCPDF related discussion.

[TCPDF Documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/docs.php)

Alternatives to TCPDF that are definitely worth trying:

## [domPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)

**Key Features**

- handles most CSS 2.1 and a few CSS3 properties, including @import, @media & @page rules
- supports external stylesheets, either local or through http/ftp (via fopen-wrappers)
- supports complex tables, including row & column spans, separate & collapsed border models, individual cell styling

[domPDF Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Introduction?tm=6)

Helpful tutorial: http://kyokasuigetsu25.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/how-to-use-dompdf-with-css/

## [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)

Examples (both PHP and generated PDF) can be found [here](http://mpdf1.com/common/mpdf/examples/) and [here](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/examples).

[mPDF Documentation](http://mpdf1.com/manual/)

Comment: links are forbidden

Comment: I feel that links should be allowed when they are to official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

in my case server added slashes to double quotes - tcpdf ignored attributes like style without warning. so I removed slashes by stripslashes function

Answer (score 1):

well there is a work around that I found :

```
<h1>Heading<small>Text(is smaller than heading.)</small></h1>
```

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code you provided, and changed the color to red for 'Visit - www.bookings.7sisters.in' using inline CSS.

See my sample output at https://www.box.com/s/520e9e1f4976802696ec

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 0):

There is no PHP library which supports fully CSS. TCPDF does quite nice job with relatively good performance even for larger strings. Check out examples e.g. [006](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/), [007](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_007/), [21](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_021/) or [061](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_061/).