# HTML in TCPDF and different margins

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, margins

I am trying to create a PDF (TCPDF library), using the "writeHTML" method to fill 4 pages of HTML content fine. The problem was that i need to use a 5cm left margin in the pair pages and a 5cm right margin in the impair pages, but the writeHTML only get the default margins of the page and i cant change it.

i use this sample code:

```
ob_start();
require_once('../classes/TCPDF-master/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
//add page
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
//set first margin
$pdf->SetMargins(50, 10, 10); //margin from left
//write html
$pdf->writeHTML('some html that fills 4 pages', true, false, true, false, '');
//output
$pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');
```

I need to change the margins of impair pages to:

```
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 10, 50);
```

How can i do that?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does TCPDF ignore my inline CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395171/why-does-tcpdf-ignore-my-inline-css)