# TCPDF ignored some CSS

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am trying to use TCPDF to create a simple table with the following design:

```html
<style>
  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  td,
  th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <h2>HTML Table</h2>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

But when I use the following code in TCPDF it ignores the colors in the CSS:

```
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
    $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
    $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE . ' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0, 64, 255), array(0, 64, 128));
    $pdf->setFooterData(array(0, 64, 0), array(0, 64, 128));

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // set default font subsetting mode
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

    // Set font
    // dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
    // print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
    // helvetica or times to reduce file size.
    $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

    // Add a page
    // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // get HTMl file and turn to a raw string
    $html =  view('my-html-file')->render(); // it's a method in Laravel that converts the HTML to string

    // Print text using writeHTMLCell()
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $blade_view_html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // Close and output PDF document
    // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
    $pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
}
```

The result is different:

[image: no css]

In the docs I did not find any reason as to why specifically (maybe) this CSS rule is not supported, because some other CSS rules are supported, for example:

https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_048/

Comment: Just to clarify first : Do you mean in this case the css `tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }` is ignored and you want to know the reason ?

Comment: Yes (and make the css work)

Comment: And then how do I know when it's going to work and it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCPDF has a very limited CSS support. It doesn't support all attributes. (Actually there is no PHP PDF library which supports fully CSS up to the present moment).

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395171/why-does-tcpdf-ignore-my-inline-css) and consult the [official documentation](https://tcpdf.org/docs/) if you have further questions

For your case, one of the ways to generate the pdf is to add the class to required rows , such as using the following class:

```
  .grey1 {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
```

So, first create the following HTML (html1.html)

```
<style>
  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  td,
  th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  
  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }

  .grey1 {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }


</style>

<body>

  <h2>HTML Table</h2>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grey1">
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grey1">
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="grey1">
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Then, you can use PHP such as the following to generate the PDF:

```
<?php
require_once('./tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('./tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);


// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Ken Lee');
$pdf->SetTitle('PDF');
$pdf->SetSubject('PDF');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, Createch');


// $pdf->SetProtection(array('copy'), '', null, 0, null);


// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);

// remove default footer
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 12);

$pdf->AddPage();

 
$html=file_get_contents('html1.html');

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');



$y1=chr(mt_rand(65, 90));
$y2=chr(mt_rand(65, 90));
$y3=chr(mt_rand(48, 57));
$y4=chr(mt_rand(65, 90));
$y5=chr(mt_rand(48, 57));
$y6=chr(mt_rand(65, 90));
$y7=chr(mt_rand(48, 57));
$y8=chr(mt_rand(48, 57));
$y9=chr(mt_rand(65, 90));

$ry=$y1.$y2.$y3.$y4.$y5.$y6.$y7.$y8.$y9;


 $pdf->Output($ry.".pdf",'FD');


?>
```

The result will be :

[image]

Comment: thank you, so flexbox is out of the question here and I will need to use some other methods (or maybe some special method of TCPDF) to do simple things like centering the title for example?

Comment: Yes , up till now it (the current version) does not have full CSS support so we have to accept some of its limitations.